# Read 3 column csv and group some elements

Tags: python

I have a csv with `3 columns (date, name, number)` and it is about 20K rows long. I want to create a dictionary keyed by date whose value is a dictionary of name:number for that date. On top of that, I want add some elements together if the name contains a key word so they would be listed as keyword:sum of numbers, rather than their individual entries.

E.g. If the csv had four entries

```
 6/17/84, Blackcat, 10, 
 6/17/84, Dog, 20, 
 6/17/84, Tabbycat, 12,
 6/17/84, Lizard, 5
```

and the keyword is `cat`, the result should be

```
{6/17/84: {'Dog':20, 'Lizard':5, 'cat':22}}
```

Here's what I came up with. Is there a better way?

```
def dict_of_csv(file_name, group_labels_with):
    complete_dict = {}
    key_word = [x.lower() for x in group_labels_with]
    for i in file_name:
        key = i[1].lower()
        key_value = int(i[2])
        row_date = time.strptime(i[0], "%m/%d/%y")
        if row_date not in complete_dict:
            complete_dict[row_date] = {}
            for name in key_word:
                complete_dict[row_date][name] = 0
        if any(name in key for name in key_word):
            for name in key_word:
                if name in key:
                    key = name
            complete_dict[row_date][key] += key_value
        else:
            complete_dict[row_date][key] = key_value
    return complete_dict
```

Comment: If this code works and you just want to improve it, you should take it over to [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead. If something isn't working, you need to explain the error or bad behavior you're encountering.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for the direction. I've posted it over, since as far as I can tell it's working.

Comment: If you moved it to the other site, please delete this question from here. Cross-posting the same question in multiple Stack Exchange sites is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code using `setdefault`

```
keyword = "cat"
my_d = {}

with open("in.csv") as f: # use with to open your file as it will automatically close it.
    for line in f:
        a, b, c = line.rstrip().split(",")[:3] # account for missing delimiter after last element
        c = int(c) 
        my_d.setdefault(a, {keyword:0}) # set default key/value using keyword
        if keyword in b.lower(): # if keyword is in the string b add the value to keyword
            my_d[a][keyword] += c
        else:
            my_d[a][b] = c# else add new key/value

print(my_d)

{'6/17/84': {' Dog': 20, ' Lizard': 5, 'cat': 22}}
```

I left out parsing your date `row_date = time.strptime(i[0], "%m/%d/%y")` as I could not see any reason to need do it.

If you want order use and OrderedDict:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
keyword = "cat"
my_d = OrderedDict()
with open("in.csv") as f:
    for line in f:
        a, b, c = line.rstrip().split(",")[:3]
        c = int(c)
        my_d.setdefault(a, {keyword:0})
        if keyword in b.lower():
            my_d[a][keyword] += c
        else:
            my_d[a][b]= c
```

which from the input:

```
6/17/84, Blackcat, 10, 
6/17/84, Dog, 20,
6/17/84, Tabbycat, 12,
6/17/84, Lizard, 5
6/18/84, Blackcat, 10,
6/18/84, Dog, 20,
6/18/84, Tabbycat, 12,
6/18/84, Lizard, 5
```

Outputs:

```
OrderedDict([('6/17/84', {' Dog': 20, ' Lizard': 5, 'cat': 22}), ('6/18/84', {' Dog': 20, ' Lizard': 5, 'cat': 22})])
```

If you want to parse the dates, use datetime:

```
from datetime import datetime
with open("in.csv") as f:
    for line in f:
        a, b, c = line.rstrip().split(",")[:3]
        c = int(c)
        a = datetime.strptime(a, "%m/%d/%y")
        my_d.setdefault(a, {keyword:0})
        if keyword in b.lower():
            my_d[a][keyword] += c
        else:
            my_d[a][b]= c
print(my_d)
{datetime.datetime(1984, 6, 17, 0, 0): {' Dog': 20, ' Lizard': 5, 'cat': 22}, datetime.datetime(1984, 6, 18, 0, 0): {' Dog': 20, ' Lizard': 5, 'cat': 22}}
```

Comment: The reason I was thinking to parse out the date is that later I'll want to order the dictionary by date. I can't do that if I leave it as a string, right?

Comment: dicts have no order, you can  use an OrderedDict of you want some order, or sort the keys using sorted and loop  over your dict accessing the dict from the sorted dict.keys.